# Discover Software Loader - Painfully Slow and Barely Operable on Lubuntu 22.04

Tags: lubuntu, 22.04, discover-software-center

On Lububtu 22.04 the Discover software loader is painfully slow.  I can not scroll down to see the packages and it crashes often.  Is there a fix or work around?

Comment: Lubuntu 22.04 LTS comes with more than just Discover for software; eg. https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/4/Installing_Updating_and_Removing_Software.html  (Note: *that manual link applies to 22.04 only until 22.10 is released later this month*)  I tend to avoid Discover myself (*too much [network] latency*) preferring other options (*Package manager that doesn't come by default with Lubuntu, or just CLI directly*)

Comment: It is interesting that Discover is just problematic on one install, a desktop with the most memory and best cpu. I purged Discover and then tried to load with Apt-get install.  It did not appear on the menu so I repeated and it said it was already installed.  I then used Muon to install all Discover related packages.  Discover is back but still painfully slow on this system.  odd

Comment: Sorry I only use Discover in QA, and that's largely a quick look around at it to ensure it works. The box I'm using now is a 2008 dell, thus doesn't have a lot of resources to spare, but even if on a more modern device.. I'd likely just `apt-cache search`, `snap search` etc & use CLI.  To explore; I'd use *top* type tools (`htop` is included by default & maybe a starting point, but I may use many others too, eg. `iotop` if I suspect its IO, `iftop` if ... etc) to explore. To get advice from Lubuntu *devs* using their [discourse](https://discourse.lubuntu.me/) may help, even IRC rather than Q&A